# PrimeReact DataTable dynamic columns from custom component

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I want to render the columns dynamically which are given inside the childeren of the **ParentComponent** as **CustomColumn**s like this:

```
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';

function TetsPage(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <ParentComponent>
            <CustomColumn field="name" header="Name" />
        </ParentComponent>
    );
}

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    ................................
    render(): JSX.Element {        
        // result:   <Column field="name" header="Name" />
        // expected: <Column field="name" header="Name" sortable={true}/>
        return (
            <DataTable value={this.state.list}>
                {this.props.children}
            </DataTable>
        );
     }
}


export class CustomColumn extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    .................................
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <Column field={this.props.field} header={this.props.header} sortable={true} />
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is the **DataTable** component renders its own **Column** components instead of my **CustomColumn** which is customized/extended version of the **Column** component.

How can I get my **CustomColumn**s rendered as dynamic columns inside the **DataTable**?

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-darkness-5vh9n)

Comment: can you add this code in codesandbox or jsfiddle ?

Comment: @NihalSaxena I've added the link for CodeSandbox;)

Comment: what is the customised part in CustomColumn ?

Comment: @NihalSexane normally sortable is false. If it can be rendered from the CustomColumn then it will be true.

Comment: check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chaplygin-ky4dt

Comment: @NihalSaxena I see what you try to do but the purpose of the `CustomColumn` component is to reduce the complexity during defining the columns. `sortable` is just an example. Imagine that there will be also filters, formatters... based on conditions. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok now i got what you are trying to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the updated sandbox for the same https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-snow-qlp8c

It's actually a very good question! After lot of headbanging, I found the solution. Actually, the problem is not the way you wrote the react component, it is the problem with the `Column` of `DataTable`. If you look in their GITHUB code, you will find it is just a `Component` with `defaultProps`. You just need to pass `sortable` as a `defaultProps` to your `CustomColumn` component and TADA! It should work.

I would like to add why it was working with the props for `field` and `header`, it's because when the `Column` was instantiated the `field` and `header` was instantiated with `props` so `defaultProps` doesn't come to picture. But when you were passing `sortable` from `CustomColumn` there was no way for React to understand it has to re-instantiate the `props` again as Component is already instantiated and there is no change for the props as the `Column` component is just a Component with `defaultProps`. It is very lame for `primereact` folks to design components in this manner. You can raise an issue in their GITHUB as well